# not able to create a dynamic form in Delphi 7

Tags: delphi

I have put together this code for creating a dynamic form

```
unit Unit1;

 interface

 uses
    Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
    Dialogs, StdCtrls;

  type
    TForm1 = class(TForm)
   Button1: TButton;
   procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
   { Private declarations }
  public
   { Public declarations }
  end;


  type
    TForm2 = class(TForm)
     private
       { Private declarations }
    public
      { Public declarations }
    end;

  var
    Form2: TForm2;
    Form1: TForm1;

implementation

  {$R *.dfm}

  procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
 var
     a:TForm2;
 begin
     a:=TForm2.Create(nil);
   end;
```

end.

I get an error saying resource tform2 cannot be found. What must i do?

Thanks

Comment: This isn't exactly the duplicate of the tagged question though they are related.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are calling the `TForm.Create()` constructor that loads the TForm contents from a DFM, but your project does not have a DFM for TForm2, which is why you are getting the resource error. To skip that, you need to use the `TForm.CreateNew()` constructor instead.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  a: TForm2;
begin
  a := TForm2.CreateNew(nil, 0);
  ...
end;
```

Answer (score 6):

In Delphi you must declare only one form per unit, also each form needs a dfm file, that file store the form definition and components properties. In your code you have this error because the application can't found the dfm file for the *TForm2* form. So to fix the problem just create a new form (TForm2) in a separate unit and then add the unit a name to the unit where you need to call the *TForm2*.

Comment: critically important to remove the $R in the new unit.

Comment: There's no indication in the question that there's supposed to be a dfm for the second form class. You can declare as many form classes as you want in a single unit.

Comment: Negative. MUST clause in the answer is incorrect, there is no such limitation. See also TCustomForm.CreateNew